# Core Data Memory Efficient Migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, core-data

I am currently building a CoreData migration for an app which has 200k / 500k average rows of data per entity. There are currently 15 entities within the CoreData Model.

This is the 7th migration I have built for this app, all of the previous have been simple (add 1or 2 column style) migrations, which have not been any trouble and have not needed any mapping models.

**This Migration**

The migration we are working on is fairly sizeable in comparison to previous migrations and adds a new entity between two existing entities. This requires a custom NSEntityMigrationPolicy which we have built to map the new entity relationships. We also have a *.xcmappingmodel, which defines the mapping between model 6 and the new model 7.

We have implemented our own subclass of NSMigrationManager (as per http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html + [http://www.amazon.com/Core-Data-Management-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1937785084/ref=dp_ob_image_bk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937785084)).

**The Problem**

Apple uses the migrateStoreFromURL method of NSMigrationManager to migrate the model, however, this seems to be built for low/medium dataset sizes, which do not overload the memory.

We are finding that the app crashes due to memory overload (@ 500-600mb on iPad Air/iPad 2) as a result of the following apple method not frequently dumping the memory on data transfer.

```
[manager migrateStoreFromURL:sourceStoreURL type:type options:nil withMappingModel:mappingModel toDestinationURL:destinationStoreURL destinationType:type destinationOptions:nil error:error];
```

**Apple's Suggested Solution**

Apple suggest that we should divide the *.xcmappingmodel up into a series of mapping models per individual entities - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmCustomizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH8-SW2. This would work neatly with the progressivelyMigrateURL methods defined in the above NSMigrationManager subclasses. However, we are not able to use this method as once entity alone will still lead to a memory overload due to the size of one entity by itself.

My guess would be that we would need to write our own migrateStoreFromURL method, but would like to keep this as close to as Apple would have intended as possible. Has anyone done this before and/or have any ideas for how we could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that heavy migrations are not good for iOS and should be avoided at literally any cost.  They were never designed to work on a memory constrained device.

Having said that, a few question for you before we discuss a resolution:

1. Is the data recoverable?  Can you download it again or is this user data?
2. Can you resolve the relationships between the entities without having the old relationship in place?  Can it be reconstructed?

I have a few solutions but they are data dependent, hence the questions back to you.

### Update 1

> The data is not recoverable and cannot be re-downloaded. The data is formed from user activity within the application over a time period (reaching up to 1 year in the past). The relationships are also not reconstructable, unless we store them before we lose access to the old relationships.

Ok, what you are describing is the worst case and therefore the hardest case.  Fortunately it isn't unsolvable.

First, Heavy migration is not going to work.  We must write code to solve this issue.

#### First Option

My preferred solution is to do a lightweight migration that only **adds** the new relationship between the (now) three entities, it does not remove the old relationship.  This lightweight migration will occur in SQLite and will be very quick.

Once that migration has been completed then we iterate over the objects and set up the new relationship based on the old relationship.  This can be done as a background process or it can be done piece meal as the objects are used, etc.  That is a business decision.

Once that conversion as been completed you can then do another migration, if needed, to remove the old relationship.  This step is not necessary but it does help to keep the model clean.

#### Second Option

Another option which has value is to export and re-import the data.  This has the added value of setting up code to back up the user's data in a format that is readable on other platforms.  It is fairly simple to export the data out to JSON and then set up an import routine that pulls the data into the new model along with the new relationship.

The second option has the advantage of being cleaner but requires more code as well as a "pause" in the user's activities.  The first option can be done without the user even being aware there is a migration taking place.

Comment: Yes, i have been coming to the same conclusions based on what i have been reading. However, in this case id love to find a way to do this. In the future I am building ways to shrink the data considerably.  

The data is not recoverable and cannot be re-downloaded. The data is formed from user activity within the application over a time period (reaching up to 1 year in the past). The relationships are also not reconstructable, unless we store them before we lose access to the old relationships.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I will try the first option. Ill let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly then you have one entity that is so big that when migrating this entity does cause the memory overload. In this case, how about splitting the migration of this one entity in several steps and therefore doing only some properties per each migration iteration?

That way you won't need to write your own code but you can benefit form the "standard" code.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. I agree with your points, but this will only be a short term fix as in the end the data will become to big even for one attribute. I'd like to programatically determine the batch size if possible to prevent it long term. Don't mind having to write my own code if required.